# Can camtasia record a new video while rendering

Tags: video, video-editing, rendering, camtasia

It is rendering an old video and is taking up too much time. Is it possible to record a new video while this one is rendering?

Comment: What happened when you tired?

Comment: I didn't have the courage lol :)